# How to compare multiple polynomials in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

[image]
I am trying to fit a second order polynomial to various curves on a binary image using MATLAB `polyfit` function.There are many such curves on the image, and the coordinates of the pixels forming the curve are known.

How do I compare the co-efficients, so as to arrive at one approximation to all such curves?

Here are some co-efficients of such curves:

```
 0.0010126     -1.5981       1074.8
 0.0024871     -3.3327       1866.3
 0.002662      -3.7067       1631.4
 0.0025574     -4.5129       2148.4
 0.002114      -3.3457       2195.6
 0.0015383     -2.6023       1682.9
```

Comment: Can you use polyfit on a all the data at once?

Comment: No. These curves are the edges of the ribs on a chest x ray. They are slightly different from each other, but have a characteristic similarity.

Comment: Could you share a sample of data? What is the difference between the curves. You ask how to compare them, but according to what criteria?A little context would help a lot here.

Comment: I want to detect the rib edges on a chest X ray. Each of the rib edges are different and are not a continuous lines. Some are only with fragments making up the whole rib edge. It is possible to fit polynomial to each segment of the edge. But I want to study on a possibility of a general or approximated polynomial applicable to many if not all of such curves. I have added an image for ref

Comment: To find a single polynomial, you could generate a new point cloud that would mix all of your polynomial, limiting them to a x that has a meaning (short rib generates less points than long ribs, kind of..), then rerun polyfit ont hat new cloud.  Or, you could fit a curve to find the polynomial coefficient. For example, you gave 6 polynomials representing a rib each. You could make 3 polynomials (a0,a1,a2) that varies relatives to the ribs position. Actually, I tried to plot your coefficients (taken vertically) and they somewhat looks like a parabola, maybe the second approach may work.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-LXoQt2E7Cf    This is the link to the .mat file of the same image

Comment: Could you please elaborate...And yes, they would look like a parabola

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84734/discussion-between-prashanth-and-pier-yves-lessard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you share, this is the best answer I can give.
I see two methods:

**Method #1,**

Instead of making N polynomials (if N is the number of ribs), you could fit a curve for all the ribs at once. Of course, for that, you will need to have a common (0,0) coordinate, in other word, stack them one over the other on your image. Since you are able to make a distinction between the ribs, that means that you can already isolate them, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Or if you prefer, you can generate a new cloud of points with the polynomials you already found.

```
coeffs = [0.0010126, -1.5981, 1074.8; 0.0024871, -3.3327, 1866.3];
x = linspace(0,1000,1000); % fictives points
merged_x = [x x];
merged_y = [ polyval(coeffs(1,:), x), polyval(coeffs(2,:),x)];
coeffs_final = polyfit(merged_x, merged_y, 2);
figure
hold on
plot(polyval(coeffs(1,:), x), 'red')
plot(polyval(coeffs(2,:), x), 'blue')
plot(polyval(coeffs_final, x), 'black')
```

[image]

**Method #2**

You could fit 3 polynomials to find the values of the coefficient you already have found. If we take the first polynomial you provided, then 
$a_2=0.0010126$ $a_1=-1.5981$ $a_0=1074.8$

You could fit a curve that would follow all $a_2$, another for all $a_1$, and same for all $a_0$. This would yield 9 new coefficients (3 polynomials) that will allow you to find your polynomials based on the rib position.

Here's an example

```
coeffs = [ 0.0010126     -1.5981       1074.8;
    0.0024871     -3.3327       1866.3;
 0.002662      -3.7067       1631.4;
 0.0025574     -4.5129       2148.4;
 0.002114      -3.3457       2195.6;
 0.0015383     -2.6023       1682.9 ];

x = linspace(0,1000,1000); %fictive value
ribs_count = size(coeffs, 1);
a2 = polyfit(1:ribs_count, coeffs(:,1)', 2); % careful to the ' symbol that transpose the column into a row
a1 = polyfit(1:ribs_count, coeffs(:,2)', 2);
a0 = polyfit(1:ribs_count, coeffs(:,3)', 2);

figure
for rib=1:ribs_count
    subplot(6,1,rib);
    hold on
    new_coeffs = [polyval(a2,rib), polyval(a1,rib), polyval(a0,rib)];
    plot(x, polyval(new_coeffs, x), 'red')
    plot(x, polyval(coeffs(rib,:), x), 'blue')
end
```

[image]